# Configuring auth realm inside application

Tags: java, authentication, ejb, jaas

Is it possible to configure a realm (define a realm name and how it should retrieve a user and passwords) inside a Java EE application?

The thing is that I want to have authentication on my website and utilize JAAS to have information for EJB when using @RolesAllowed annotations. That user information would be fetched from database that is application specific.

Also I would like to skip that step when each deployer should configure his own application server to include some specific realm - I want that to be done inside application when it is deployed.

Is it possible to do? Summarized - is it possible to have working @RolesAllowed annotations on EJB and some authentication that does not include tinkering with application server?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a JASPIC auth module. This is part of the Java EE 6 standard. They can be programmatically initialized from within the application and the code can be inside the application as well.

Note that for EJB usage authentication has to haven via either a regular HTTP request or via SOAP. JASPIC does not (yet) support authentication for remote EJB connections.